# A function returns a MsgBox 10 times?

Tags: vba, excel

Found a function  on [Excelguru](http://Excelguru.no) which I changed a few things in and gonna edit some more. The idea is to use this to register worked hours and minutes.

There is one thing in this I don't understand: if I type the wrong time in the column reff I get a msg that its wrong, but it wont disappear unless I click it 10 times. I cant see what Im doing wrong. The entire code is posted and Im grateful for any help.

Use his function as part of the formula in the sheet like: `TimeValue($E2;$F2;"16:00";"18:00";B2;9;C2)`

```
Function TimeValue(FromTime As String, ToTime As String, StartTime As String, StopTime As String, Optional Weekday As String, Optional Daynr As Integer, Optional Holiday As String)
    Dim x As Long
    Dim F As Double
    Dim T As Double
    Dim Start As Double
    Dim Stopp As Double
    Dim Min As Long
    Dim Day As Integer
    Dim OverMid As Boolean

    Select Case LCase(Weekday)
        Case "mandag"
            Day = 1
        Case "tirsdag"
            Day = 2
        Case "onsdag"
            Day = 3
        Case "torsdag"
            Day = 4
        Case "fredag"
            Day = 5
        Case "lordag"
            Day = 6
        Case "sondag"
            Day = 7
        Case "x"
            Day = 8
        Case Else
            Day = 0
    End Select

    OverMid = False

    If LCase(Holiday) = "x" Then Day = 8

    If Len(FromTime) = 0 Or Len(ToTime) = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Len(FromTime) <> 5 Then
        MsgBox ("Use format TT:MM - From time is wrong:" & FromTime)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Len(ToTime) <> 5 Then
        MsgBox ("Use format TT:MM - To time is wrong:" & ToTime)
        Exit Function
    End If

    F = Val(Left(FromTime, 2)) * 60 + Val(Right(FromTime, 2))
    T = Val(Left(ToTime, 2)) * 60 + Val(Right(ToTime, 2))

    Start = Val(Left(StartTime, 2)) * 60 + Val(Right(StartTime, 2))
    Stopp = Val(Left(StopTime, 2)) * 60 + Val(Right(StopTime, 2))

    If T = 0 Then T = 24 * 60
    If T < F Then
        T = T + 24 * 60
        OverMid = True
    End If

    If Stopp = 0 Then Stopp = 24 * 60

    For x = F + 1 To T
        If x > Start And x <= Stopp Then
            Min = Min + 1
        End If
    Next x

    If OverMid = True Then
        For x = 0 To Val(Left(ToTime, 2)) * 60 + Val(Right(ToTime, 2))
            If x > Start And x <= Stopp Then
                Min = Min + 1
            End If
        Next x
    End If

    'If weekday is set, equal to day
    If Daynr <> 0 Then
        If Daynr <> 9 Then
            If Day <> Daynr Then Min = 0
        End If

        If Daynr = 9 And (Day > 5) Then
            Min = 0
        End If
    End If

    TimeValue = Min / 60

End Function
```

And the sub in the sheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim streng As String
 Dim k As Long
 Dim r As Long

 k = Target.Column
 r = Target.Row


 If Cells(1, k) = "P" Then
  If Cells(r, k) = "x" Then
   Cells(r, 4) = "x"
   Else
   Cells(r, 4) = ""
  End If
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: put a break point at the first line of the function and start stepping through the code.  That's probably the easiest way to identify why the code is running multiple times (or generating multiple message boxes).

Comment: please post the code that is calling this funcion

Comment: What is calling this function? The function itself won't popup multiple message boxes, so I think that the (unknown) calling code must be the culprit

Comment: added the sub that's in the sheet.

Comment: Did you put the function in 10 cells all of which return an error?

Comment: @GSerg The function is part of the formula in the sheet in 8 different columns. each sheet is the month and each row is the weekday

Comment: Well, since you make changes to the WorkSheet from inside the Worksheet_Change() event, I would expect that you trigger the event once for each change until it reaches a stable state.

Comment: @VincentG Thought about that as a possibility and an answer, but I cant find a way around that with my vba "skills"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message boxes really don't belong in UDFs (VBA functions meant to be used as spreadsheet functions).

Instead of the message box you could use code like:

```
If Len(FromTime) <> 5 Then
        TimeValue = "Error! Use format TT:MM - From time is wrong:" & FromTime
        Exit Function
```

Or perhaps:

```
If Len(FromTime) <> 5 Then
       TimeValue = CVErr(xlErrValue)
       Exit Function
```

This later will cause `#VALUE!` to display in the cell. Include enough documentation in your spreadsheet so that users can interpret such error values.

Comment: Tried them both and they generated the same type of error which I can work with. Thx for pointing out a simple way to fix this. Hard to see the easiest answer sometimes ;)